# Proof of the continuous function having tangent plane has directional derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

Suppose that the continuous function $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ has a tangent plane at the point $(x_0, y_0, f(x_0, y_0))$

Prove that the function $f$ has directional derivatives in all directions at rhe point $(x_0, y_0)$

---

I guess that I need to use the definitions of the tangent plane and directional derivatives. Hopefully this is right!

But I am telling to you so honestly, I am not good to prove a theorem. Even if somebody gives a hint, I cannot use it to prove this properly. Thus, show me and teach me this proof step by step. Thank you so much for helping:)

Comment: how do you define the tangent plane? What object exists given this data?

Comment: The deifinition of tangent plane $lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-g(x,y)}{\sqrt {(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2}}=0$ Where $g(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$ @JamesS.Cook

Comment: @jamesS.Cook please help me!

Comment: see the answer. (not mine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tangent plane at the point $\;u=(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))\;$ of the function $\;g(x,y,z):=(x,y,z)\;,\;\;z:=f(x,y)\;$ ,  is just
$$\nabla g(x_0,y_0,z_0)\cdot(x-x_0\,,\,y-y_0\,,\,z-f(x_0,y_0))=0$$

This means the gradient of the function $\;f\;$ exists at $\,(x_0,y_0)\;$ and from another question you asked this means there exists the directional derivative of $\;f\;$ in any diretion at the above point.

Comment: thanks. This is much better than the direction from the definition I was just pursuing.

Comment: Yes I need to prove the existence of the directional derivative of $f$ in any direction at the above point. But how?

Comment: @B11b, please read carefully the answer *and then* go back and check the questions you asked yesterday!

Comment: One minute! :) @DonAntonio I am writing what I understand

Comment: If you want take 10 minutes: just stop writing "but how" and things like **and go** read some of the answers you got yesterday!

Comment: $\sum {(x-x_0, y-y_0, z-f(x_0,y_0)\frac {\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x_0, y_0, z_0)}=0$

Comment: Now, I have the above equation. Here, I am tring to obtain that $\nabla g(x_0,y_0, z_0)\cdot(x-x_0, y-y_0, z-f(x_0, y_0)= D_{(x-x_0, y-y_0, z-f(x_0, y_0)}g(x_0,y_0, z_0)$ like you did yesterday. Right? @DonAntonio

Comment: Your notation is a bit unclear to me, but I guess you have the right idea.